# NavigationSevice in Universal App

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, win-universal-app

Using the MVVM structure, i wish to redirect my View to a new viewpage from my ViewModel.
NavigationService seems to be able to accomplish this. By calling the NavigationService.Navigate to a new URI..

My problem is that i DON'T have NavigationService in Windows Universal App.
Is there a way to implement it?

I've been using: this.Frame.Navigate to navigate between views, but I can only use this on the codebehind of my view :(

How can i accomplish navigating my view from my viewmodel?

Comment: Ive answered this is in your other question

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you use any library/framework? Anyway, [here](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/557296/SharingplusCode-3aplusAddingplusNavigationService) is an article about how you can implement navigation service to your project.